# patterns searching in text

Tags: python

I have text file as follows seq.txt

```
>S1
AACAAGAAGAAAGCCCGCCCGGAAGCAGCTCAATCAGGAGGCTGGGCTGGAATGACAGCG
CAGCGGGGCCTGAAACTATTTATATCCCAAAGCTCCTCTCAGATAAACACAAATGACTGC
GTTCTGCCTGCACTCGGGCTATTGCGAGGACAGAGAGCTGGTGCTCCATTGGCGTGAAGT
CTCCAGGGCCAGAAGGGGCCTTTGTCGCTTCCTCACAAGGCACAAGTTCCCCTTCTGCTT
CCCCGAGAAAGGTTTGGTAGGGGTGGTGGTTTAGTGCCTATAGAACAAGGCATTTCGCTT
CCTAGACGGTGAAATGAAAGGGAAAAAAAGGACACCTAATCTCCTACAAATGGTCTTTAG
TAAAGGAACCGTGTCTAAGCGCTAAGAACTGCGCAAAGTATAAATTATCAGCCGGAACGA
GCAAACAGACGGAGTTTTAAAAGATAAATACGCATTTTTTTCCGCCGTAGCTCCCAGGCC
AGCATTCCTGTGGGAAGCAAGTGGAAACCCTATAGCGCTCTCGCAGTTAGGAAGGAGGGG
TGGGGCTGTCCCTGGATTTCTTCTCGGTCTCTGCAGAGACAATCCAGAGGGAGACAGTGG
ATTCACTGCCCCCAATGCTTCTAAAACGGGGAGACAAAACAAAAAAAAACAAACTTCGGG
TTACCATCGGGGAACAGGACCGACGCCCAGGGCCACCAGCCCAGATCAAACAGCCCGCGT
CTCGGCGCTGCGGCTCAGCCCGACACACTCCCGCGCAAGCGCAGCCGCCCCCCCGCCCCG
GGGGCCCGCTGACTACCCCACACAGCCTCCGCCGCGCCCTCGGCGGGCTCAGGTGGCTGC
GACGCGCTCCGGCCCAGGTGGCGGCCGGCCGCCCAGCCTCCCCGCCTGCTGGCGGGAGAA
ACCATCTCCTCTGGCGGGGGTAGGGGCGGAGCTGGCGTCCGCCCACACCGGAAGAGGAAG
TCTAAGCGCCGGAAGTGGTGGGCATTCTGGGTAACGAGCTATTTACTTCCTGCGGGTGCA
CAGGCTGTGGTCGTCTATCTCCCTGTTGTTC

>S2
ACACGCATTCACTAAACATATTTACTATGTGCCAGGCACTGTTCTCAGTGCTGGGGATAT
AGCAGTGAAGAAACAGAAACCCTTGCACTCACTGAGCTCATATCTTAGGGTGAGAAACAG
TTATTAAGCAAGATCAGGATGGAAAACAGATGGTACGGTAGTGTGAAATGCTAAAGAGAA
AAATAACTACGGAAAAGGGATAGGAAGTGTGTGTATCGCAGTTGACTTATTTGTTCGCGT
TGTTTACCTGCGTTCTGTCTGCATCTCCCACTAAACTGTAAGCTCTACATCTCCCATCTG
TCTTATTTACCAATGCCAACCGGGGCTCAGCGCAGCGCCTGACACACAGCAGGCAGCTGA
CAGACAGGTGTTGAGCAAGGAGCAAAGGCGCATCTTCATTGCTCTGTCCTTGCTTCTAGG
AGGCGAATTGGGAAATCCAGAGGGAAAGGAAAAGCGAGGAAAGTGGCTCGCTTTTGGCGC
TGGGGAAGAGGTGTACAGTGAGCAGTCACGCTCAGAGCTGGCTTGGGGGACACTCTCACG
CTCAGGAGAGGGACAGAGCGACAGAGGCGCTCGCAGCAGCGCGCTGTACAGGTGCAACAG
CTTAGGCATTTCTATCCCTATTTTTACAGCGAGGGACACTGGGCCTCAGAAAGGGAAGTG
CCTTCCCAAGCTCCAACTGCTCATAAGCAGTCAACCTTGTCTAAGTCCAGGTCTGAAGTC
CTGGAGCGATTCTCCACCCACCACGACCACTCACCTACTCGCCTGCGCTTCACCTCACGT
GAGGATTTTCCAGGTTCCTCCCAGTCTCTGGGTAGGCGGGGAGCGCTTAGCAGGTATCAC
CTATAAGAAAATGAGAATGGGTTGGGGGCCGGTGCAAGACAAGAATATCCTGACTGTGAT
TGGTTGAATTGGCTGCCATTCCCAAAACGAGCTTTGGCGCCCGGTCTCATTCGTTCCCAG
CAGGCCCTGCGCGCGGCAACATGGCGGGGTCCAGGTGGAGGTCTTGAGGCTATCAGATCG
GTATGGCATTGGCGTCCGGGCCCGCAAGGCG

.
.
.
.
```

I have to count patterns in these sequences to achieve python script

```
import re

infile = open("seq.txt", 'r')

out = open("pat.txt", 'w')

pattern = re.compile("GAAAT", flags=re.IGNORECASE)


for line in infile:
   line = line.strip("\n")
   if line.startswith('>'):
      name = line
   else:
      s = re.findall(pattern,line)

      print '%s:%s' %(name,s)
      out.write('%s:\t%s\n' %(name,len(s)))
```

But it is giving the wrong result. The script is reading line by line.

```
S1 : 0
S1 : 0
S1 : 0
S1 : 0
S2 : 0
S2 : 1
S2 : 0   
S2 : 1
```

But I want output as follows:

```
S1 : 0    
S2 : 2
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: CODE FORMATTING! See the `{}` button? Use it.

Comment: @minitech: It's not much better now...

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Yes, yes it is much better.

Comment: I tried cutting down on the waste of vertical space, too.

Comment: For those not familiar, DNA uses C, G, A and T to describe gene sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hit counter, zero it if `line.startswith('>')`. Increment by `len(s)` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This code might be helpful for you:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("GAAAT", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

with open('seq.txt') as f:
    sections = f.read().split('\n\n')

    for section in sections:
        lines = section.split()
        name = lines[0].lstrip('>')
        data = ''.join(lines[1:])
        print '{0}: {1}'.format(name, len(pattern.findall(data)))
```

Example output:

```
S1: 1
S2: 2
```

Notes:

- It's assumed that two newline characters are used to separate every section as in the example.
- It's assumed that every section name is preceded by a greater than (`>`) character as in the example.
- If you already have a pattern, use `pattern.findall(data)` instead of `re.findall(pattern, data)`

Answer (score 0):

You should gather input until you enter the next pattern. This would also solve the corner case of where your pattern crosses a line boundary (not sure if that "can" happen with your data, but it looks like it).

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter. Also, have your `print` function inside the `for` loop, so it's going to iterate as many times as the `else` condition. Note that it's also not a good idea to use the variable `line` as both the iterator variable in the `for` loop *and* as another variable. It makes the code more confusing.

```
counter_dict = {}
for line in infile:
    if line[0] == '>':
        name = line[1:len(line) - 2]
        counter_dict[name] = 0
    else:
        counter_dict[name] += len(re.findall(pattern,line))

for (key, val) in counter_dict.items():
    print '%s:%s' %(key, val)
    out.write('%s:\t%s\n' %(key, val)
```